# "Custom Field Template" plugin - Content area dissapearing when switching templates

Tags: wordpress

On top of all: This is a great plugin.

But after the latest core upgrade to 3.3.1, the plugin got this big bug: If you have more than one fields template set, when switching from one template to the other, the main content area disappears. If the post/page is saved in those conditions, the main content ends up empty.

This is happening on all the sites where I have this plugin installed.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed on a later release of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could try do display it by editing your theme with code like this for every field you wish to display:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_CustomFieldName', true); ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's not related with the problem, I'm refering to the backend, when editing a page/post and switching from one custom fields template to the other.